# Load a URL Inside WebView and Make Top 20dp Invisible

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an URL to a website, which I want to load inside a WebView. The website must be scrollable up and down with the exception of the top 20dp of the page. Meaning that the header of the website must not be visible inside the WebView, without impairing the scrollability of the website overall and without overlaying the WebView with an awkward solid color View.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to inject javascript.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
   "document.getElementsByClassName('headerClassName')[0].style.display=\"none\"; "+
   "})()");
```

This will hide the header, if you know the class where the header is located.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to a tricky layout design in XML itself.

Take one FrameLayout and put WebView and a ImageView in it, Like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/whiteBG"/>
</FrameLayout>
```